# Is it good to sign saml assertion before encrypt it?

Tags: saml-2.0

I would like to ask if I signed the saml response with idp private key and encrypt saml assertion with sp public key.  Do I need to sign the saml assertion before encryption?  Is it overkill?  Do you know any standard from any official doc? Thanks.

Comment: When dealing with cryptography you should try to use a library that does it for you or at least use a well known protocol. Shipping your own cryptography is generally a bad idea as there are lots of things you can do wrong and it is better to leave this to the experts.

Comment: always use encrypt then mac, this is the best method of achieving good security. And there is no such thing as overkill in security, only beeing more paranoid then others :D

Answer (score 3):

- Encrypting with the recipient's public key guarantees that only the recipient can read the contents. Anyone can encrypt data with the recipient's public key.
- Signing with the sender's private key guarantees that only the real sender could have created the data. Anyone can validate that the data is indeed from the sender.

In SAML the most important thing for an SP is to being able to validate that the assertion is indeed from the IDP and not from some fake source. That can only be done through signing with the IDP's key. That's why signing is mandatory in the SAML standard. Encryption can be used to make sure nobody but the SP can read the contents of the assertion. That is optional in the standard.

For details see chapter 5 in the [SAML2 core specification](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56777/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-07-diff.pdf).

Comment: Also have a look at chapter 6 which details encryption, and 6.2 encryption and integrity protection are discussed.

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to encrypt and then sign the entire SAML response rather than just the assertion. This method is considered to be most secure and will be more widely accepted by SSO/Federation products.

The reason for signing the entire SAML response is a potential protocol vulnerability, where the origin of the SAML response could not be guaranteed (if the response itself weren't signed).